# Why use fs.open when we already have fs.read and fs.write?

Tags: node.js

This is kind of a noob question but I'm slightly puzzled as to why one would need `open` with `r`, `w` , `a` and all the variants of those flags. Wouldn't one simply use `readFile` or `writeFile` if s/he wanted to read or write to a file instead of using `open`?

Questions really is, what's really the difference(apart from the syntax) between `fs.open` and `fs.read`, `fs.read`?

Comment: `open` allows you to open for writing as well, whereas `read` makes it only readable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948290/confuse-about-node-js-file-write-system

Comment: Hmm..is it possible for you to show an example? Because when I tried, the second argument of `async` or the `sync` version only gave me back the `file descriptor` not the actual the content of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readFile` and `writeFile` are convenience methods -- they are one-trick ponies. for more sophisticated file i/o, you need `open`, `read`, and `write`. Much of the node file api is based on the posix spec. you need to establish a 'connection' to the file via `open` before doing anything else. From the posix spec:

> The open() function shall establish the connection between a file and
>   a file descriptor.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So, in summary `readFile` and `writeFile` can only handle one type of file descriptor but with `open` you can handle `read-write`, `append` and other multiple file descriptors at once(am I correct on this one?). However, from the node docs it wasn't quite clear on how it can be used (there wasn't any example). Upon further research I found out that a `buffer` and `fd` was needed for `read` and `write` as you mentioned. And it's starting to make sense now. Very cool. Thanks.
For others example is [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-the-file-system-in-node-js/)

Comment: think of the daft punk album 'random access ....'  -- as far as positional writes and so on, `writeFile` won't give you that sort of flexibility